# closing stdout and stderr (1>&- 2>&-) modifies exit status?

Tags: linux, bash

Does `ls -l /path/to/dir/*.extension 1>&- 2>&-`

really giving exit status as `2` even if files with `.extension` exist or am I making some mistake?

What I know by doing `1>&- 2>&-` I am closing stdout and stderr for command, and it should do nothing with exit status of command!

*But* as one expects following always works pretty fine:

```
ls -l /path/to/dir/*.extension &>/dev/null
```

exit status is `0` as expected.

Just looking for an explanation for this behaviour.

**#UNDERSTANDING**

On basis of answer given by Simon Richter:
If we do something like

```
jordan-a@hosties:exp$ echo "Life" 1>&- 
-bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

it's throwing error since echo couldn't write to stdout and 
if we do

```
jordan-a@hosties:exp$ echo "Life" 1>&- 2>&-
```

We would not even get to know the error, till the time we check `$?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are closing the file descriptors, so the program will get an error trying to write to them, and it communicates that error to you.

If you redirect the output to `/dev/null`, the write succeeds, and `ls` doesn't know that the output got discarded.